# Hor to Align my images in center in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a blog and use wordpress. From few days, when I am adding image to my articles, i am not able to align my images in center. When I align my images in center while writing post, images are in center in draft but as soon as I post my article, images are shown in left. Kindly give me an appropriate and easy solution as I am not too familiar with coding.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: one easy solution would be to use `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` on the image. But as always It highly depends on the rest of the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The style settings are probably being overridden by the theme or any active plugin. Add `style="display: block !important; margin: 0 auto !important;"` to the `<img>` tag.